# Salir de una funcion desde un $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Estoy usando la función [$.each de jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) para recorrer un `JSON`,  y dada cierta validación quiero mostrar un `alert()`, salir del `$.each` y de la función que lo contiene, sé que con `return false;` se sale de la función `$.each`, pero continua con la ejecución de la función.

Ejemplo

```
function guardarCuestionario() {
    var preguntas = JSON.parse('cadena de texto con formato JSON');

     $.each(preguntas, function () {
          value = $("input:radio[name ='" + this.ID + "']:checked").val();

          if (this.EsObligatoria && value === undefined) { 
              alert('Necesitas seleccionar una respuesta para todas las preguntas que no son opcionales');
              return false; // solamente se sale del $.each pero no de la funcion
          }
          /*
              Mas código 
          */
     });
     console.log('No quiero que continúe hasta aquí si (this.EsObligatoria && value === undefined) se cumple!!!');
     /*
         Mas código 
     */
}
```

Sé que puedo lograr lo que quiero asignando un valor a una bandera para saber si en algún momento entro en la condición y checarla al final, pero quiero saber si existe alguna forma de salir del `$.each` y de la función que la contiene en una sentencia.

Comment: No podrás salvarte de los velociraptores!

Comment: Publiqué una respuesta que hacía uso de `goto` mediante esta librería: [goto.js](http://summerofgoto.com/) Sin embargo tuve que eliminarla porque no funcionaba saltar entre funciones. La única manera de hacerlo es con un flag

Comment: Sí se puede hacer de manera nativa usando excepciones

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una posible solución es utilizar excepciones. El código sería simple:

- Envuelve la llamada a la función dentro de un `try` con un `catch` vacío.
- Cuando llegues a la condición de parada, lanza una excepción con `throw`.

Por ejemplo, en esta demostración se itera un array de 6 elementos, la condición de parada es que sólo se muestren dos de ellos, y después de eso se salta al final sin que se muestre el mensaje de "No quiero que continue hasta aquí!" (mira la consola de JavaScript para ver los resultados):

```js
function guardarCuestionario() {
    var preguntas = JSON.parse('[1,2,3,4,5,6]');
    $.each(preguntas, function(i, e) {
        if (i == 2) {
            throw "Cualquier Cosa";
        }
        console.log(e);
    });
    console.log('No quiero que continúe hasta aquí!');
}

try {
    guardarCuestionario();
} catch (e) { }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Y aplicado a tu código en particular se vería así:

```
function guardarCuestionario() {
    var preguntas = JSON.parse('cadena de texto con formato JSON');

    $.each(preguntas, function () {
        value = $("input:radio[name ='" + this.ID + "']:checked").val();

        if (this.EsObligatoria && value === undefined) { 
            alert('Necesitas seleccionar una respuesta para todas las preguntas que no son opcionales');
            throw "error"; // salta al catch
        }
        /*
        Mas código 
        */
    });
    console.log('No quiero que continúe hasta aquí si (this.EsObligatoria && value === undefined) se cumple!!!');
    /*
    Mas código 
    */ 
}

try {
    guardarCuestionario();
} catch(e) { }
```

Comment: Muy ingeniosa la solución, aunque no se sale de la función, solamente se sale del bloque delimitador, pero aun así muy buena respuesta

Comment: Si quieres que se salga de la función completamente, mueve el `try` y `catch` al lugar desde donde se llama la función y mantén el `throw` dentro de la función

Comment: Un problema con esta solución sería que si hay un error y se lanza una excepción de verdad dentro de `guardarCuestionario` no te darás cuenta a no ser que lo proceses en el `catch`

Comment: Si, de hecho, aunque solamente tendria que hacer algo como `if(e !== 'errorDefinidoPorMi') throw e;`

Comment: Sí, correcto :)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro modifiqué tu solución para hacerla 100% correcta según los comentarios.

Comment: ¡Ojo! Usar excepciones para control de flujo no se considera buena práctica en general; intenta siempre buscar una alternativa o, si necesitas utilizar este sistema, procura encapsularlo en alguna construcción de más alto nivel que esconda el manejo de excepciones.

Answer (score 6):

No hay una manera nativa de lograrlo. La función each no pertenece a la sintaxis de JavaScript, por lo tanto, su uso es el mismo que el de cualquier otra función.

Existen varias técnicas para lograr lo que deseas. Una de ellas es el uso de una excepción `StopIterationException` o similar, que puedees arrojar cuando decidas detener la iteración. Personalmente no me gusta.

Otra opción es utilizar [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) en lugar de each de jQuery. Tan pronto como encuentres la condición de paro (donde pondrías un `break`) deberas usar un `return true`, lo que indica la condición de paro para `some`. El valor de retorno de `some` deberás checarlo para saber si escaparás de la función.

function guardarCuestionario() {
    var preguntas = JSON.parse('cadena de texto con formato JSON');

```
 var escapa = preguntas.some(function () {
      value = $("input:radio[name ='" + this.ID + "']:checked").val();

      if (this.EsObligatoria && value === undefined) { 
          alert('Necesitas seleccionar una respuesta para todas las preguntas que no son opcionales');
          return true; // regresa true para indicar que debe escapar de la función
      }
      /*
          Mas código 
      */
 });
 if (escapa) {
     return;
 }
 console.log('No quiero que continúe hasta aquí si (this.EsObligatoria && value === undefined) se cumple!!!');
 /*
     Mas código 
 */
```

}

Evidentemente, sigue haciendose uso de una variable auxiliar en ambos casos (valor de retorno de `some` o la excepción cachada). Si lo que deseas es tener código más simple, probablemente te convendrá utilizar un `for` clásico.

Comment: Si, un `for` sería una solución simple, aunque prefiero usar `$.each` por su simplicidad y la legibilidad que brinda

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta La cosa es que esa legibilidad se destruye por completo si empiezas a usar formas retorcidas de salirte del bucle. Además, `each` sugiere que quieres realizar una operación para *cada* elemento, algo que contradice tu intención de romper el bucle de forma temprana.

Comment: @Marcelo lo se, como le dije a @JuanDavid tal como escribi en el ultimo parrafo, _desde el principio sabia que se podia hacer con una bandera y asi lo hice, solo queria saber si existe alguna forma de salir del `$.each` y de la función que la contiene en una sentencia_.
Ahora, por lo del each, no significa que quiera hacer X cosa **para** cada elemento, mejor dicho quiero hacer X cosa **por** cada elemento, lo de romper el bucle no tiene nada que ver, por algo existen  formas de salir del `each`/`foreach` como `break` en C#

Answer (score 3):

No entiendo cual es el problema? Si te sales del $.each con el return, es tan solo que utilices una variable como parámetro de salida... ejemplo:

```
function guardarCuestionario() {
   //... code code code
   var exit = false;
   $.each(preguntas, function () {
   
       if (this.EsObligatoria && value === undefined) { 
          exit = true;
          return false;
       }
       //... code code code
   });

   exit && return; //si no te gusta así, estas libre de utilizar un if jeje
   //... code code code
}
```

Las excepciones son buenas pero no son la respuesta para todo, y menos para este caso con jQuery que si permite detener el ciclo ;)

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration. Check the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: no hay ningun problema, solo queria saber si habia una forma de hacer X cosa, si lees el ultimo parrafo, puedes ver que especifico desde el principio que se podia hacer con una _bandera_ y asi lo hice, solo _queria saber si existe alguna forma de salir del $.each y de la función que la contiene en una sentencia_.

Comment: Ahh si, me di cuenta después que ya había puesto el comentario jajaja Si no que se ven horrible los ejemplos manejando excepciones.
PD: no te gusta programar en inglés?

Comment: Si lo hago, de hecho todo mi código está en inglés, por aquello de que alguien más de otra parte del mundo lo valla a modificar, aparte de que hay cosas que ayudan, el detalle es que esto es stackoverflow en español.. Así que trato de ser lo más fiel posible al objetivo del sitio ^_^